# Copying files into multiple directories using Python Shutil

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

I am trying to use `shutil.copytree` to copy a directory onto multiple other directories. I can't get it to work. I'm pretty sure I just need to implement `ignore_errors=True`, but I cant get it to work. How should I go about implementing 'ignore_errors=True' into

```
for CopyHere in DeleteThis:
    for CopyThis in FilestoCopy:
        shutil.copytree(CopyThis, CopyHere)
        print('Files have been copied')
```

My code is as follows:

```
import shutil
import time


DeleteThis = ['E:', 'F:']
FilestoCopy = ['C:\\Users\\2402neha\\Desktop\\Hehe']


for Directory_to_delete in DeleteThis: 
    shutil.rmtree(Directory_to_delete, ignore_errors=True)
    print('Directories have been wiped')
    time.sleep(2)


for CopyHere in DeleteThis:
    for CopyThis in FilestoCopy:
        shutil.copytree(CopyThis, CopyHere)
        print('Files have been copied')
```

Here are the error messages I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\2402neha\OneDrive\Python\Dis Cleaner\Copy paste test.py", line 17, in <module>
    shutil.copytree(CopyThis, CopyHere)
  File "C:\Users\2402neha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\shutil.py", line 309, in copytree
    os.makedirs(dst)
  File "C:\Users\2402neha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Ingen tilgang: 'E:'
```

Comment: Do you see any error messages ? because "i cant get it to work" does not tell much ..

Comment: Just to note, `CamelCase` in Python is usually only used for the names of classes. You'd more likely see `copy_this` or `copythis` for functions and names.

Answer (score 0):

Your destination is `E:`

The destination directory needs to not exist.

From the documentation for [**`shutil.copytree`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree):

> `shutil.copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None)`
>   Recursively copy an entire directory tree rooted at `src`. The destination directory, named by `dst`, must not already exist; it will be created as well as missing parent directories.

You probably want the directory name you're copying and to join it with the destination:

```
directory = os.path.basename(CopyThis)
destination = os.path.join(CopyHere, directory)
shutil.copytree(CopyThis, destination)
```